# delta value while calculating logarithm

Tags: math, logarithm, natural-logarithm

I am using a formula to calculate a parameter, the formula involves taking logarithm of a value which can be zero at times. To handle such case, I read in literature the technique to put some delta value as follows:

```
ln(delta + A)
```

Here, the paramter `A` is a real number ranging from `[0, 1]`.

What value I should assign to `delta`? Shall I assign `delta = 1`, so that `ln(delta + A)` will return `0` whenever `A` is `0`?

Further, is there any rule of choice for using natural logarithm or base10 or base2 logarithm?

Following is the formula I am using:

```
Lw = exp[ 1 / N( sum[ log( delta + Lw( x, y ) ) ] ) ]
```

Please refer to this link for explanation: [Log average luminance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb173486%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you tell us more about what the result is intended to do, what the range of values supplied as A can be?

Comment: This sounds wrong to me.  You should reassess your formulation instead of papering it over this way.

Comment: @PhilH: A is real number in range [0, 1]

Comment: Shouldnt delta be small enough nonzero number? So called epsilon? I.e. `delta=10^{-6}` ?

Comment: If that value represents a probability, then the way it's handled in statistics is to reformulate in terms of logit function.  You don't have these problems that way.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit

Comment: @duffymo It is not probability. It is luminance value of a pixel in an RGB image. So, it could be zero for black pixels which is the cause of my worry.

Comment: Logit is your solution.  Better than the delta.

Comment: Can you say what the formula is? The best way to treat 0 will depend on the rest of the formula.

Comment: @dmuir, I have updated the question with the details of the formula. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what the range of A is, it is hard to answer.

If A is generally an integer, but happens to sometimes be 0, then returning `log(A + 1)` will do what you want, but return 0 when A is 0. The question is what impact it will have on the use of the answer if you use `log(A + 1)` instead of `log(A)`, since they are mathematically different.

-- Edit --

For A as a real value in the range [0,1], the value of log(A) would be negative anyway. The sensible answer for log(0) in that circumstance is -Infinity. Most programming languages use the [IEEE 754 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for representing floating point values, and that standard includes a value for -Infinity as one of the special values. Using -Infinity here would preserve monotonicity, i.e. log(a) < log(b) if a < b, even if a == 0.

The code would depend on the implementation of log in use; unless it is certain that log(0) would return -Infinity, the obvious thing to do is just check:

```
if(A == 0)
   result = -INFINITY; // macro in math.h
else
   result = log(A);
```

as a (GNU) C example.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question. The parameter A is a real number ranging from [0, 1]

Comment: I have updated the question with details of the formula I am using. Please check once.